# Order of precedence logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

given: $$(A \rightarrow B) \vee C \rightarrow D$$

Is it (1) $$((A \rightarrow B) \vee C) \rightarrow D$$

or (2)

$$(A \rightarrow B) \vee (C \rightarrow D)$$

I've seen this image online:

[image]

And so (1) looks promising however, it seems rather strange they put a bracket around $(A \rightarrow B)$ and not $( C \rightarrow D)$ and furthermore it looks strange to me, that we first evaluate $(A \rightarrow B) \vee C$ and then to this whole statement we do: $... \rightarrow D$

Comment: [Order of precedence](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/glossary/operator_precedence) is not an universal convention; thus, in order to avoid ambiguities, uses enough parentheses.

Comment: having said that, **IF** the convention you are using is that in the table above, the formula is $((A→B)∨C)→D$

Comment: As Mauro hints at, order of precedence can be anything one wants (as long as it's consistent), or not even exist at all.  For example, there is no order of precedence for operators in Polish notation.  One can also, in fact, dismiss all three strings as nonsense, since none of them are well-formed.  You have to assume the order of precedence first, and then the answer you get only holds assuming that order of precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this formula does not require parentheses, since $\vee$ has a higher priority than $\rightarrow$. The table is correct. So it is $(A\rightarrow B)\vee (C\rightarrow D)$ or simply $A\rightarrow B\vee C\rightarrow D$.

Comment: But since $\vee$ has higher priority, you need to evaluate it like (1) no? and in your answer you said it's like (2)

Comment: The answer is (2)

Answer (score 0):

Going by the precedence table it should be (1): without parentheses, you apply the $\lor$ before the $\rightarrow$

And this is *exactly why* they put parentheses around the $(A \rightarrow B)$, because otherwise the statement would be:

$$A \rightarrow (B \lor C) \rightarrow D$$

... and then clearly another set of parentheses would be needed to disambiguate that!

But that's not what they wanted. They wanted to first have you evaluate $A \rightarrow B$, then disjunct that with $C$ to get $(A \rightarrow B) \lor C$, and finally use that statement as the antecedent of a conditional with consequent $D$.  And yes, that's strange statement, and you'll most likely never see anything like that being used for any practical application, but that of course does not mean that that can't be the statement.  It's (1)!

Finally, I am totally with Mauro's comment: precedence is not universal, which is why I *always insist* on parentheses to avoid these kinds of ambiguities.